# Identifying the origin of a focus request in Java Swing UI

Tags: java, swing, focus

I have a problem with a Swing application whereby focus will sometimes be gained by a text entry field for reasons that I am currently unable to identify. I suspect a race condition of some sort but I can't see what is causing the focus event.

The field has a focus listener attached to it so it's straight forward to add a breakpoint to the focusGained() event handler. When I do, I can see the underlying event which in turn contains an instance of CausedFocusEvent.Cause. The name field is set to "ACTIVATION".

Looking at the stack trace, I can see the following:

```
Thread [AWT-EventQueue-0] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 174 in MyPanel$3)) 
    MyPanel$3.focusGained(FocusEvent) line: 174 
    AWTEventMulticaster.focusGained(FocusEvent) line: not available 
    InputField(Component).processFocusEvent(FocusEvent) line: not available 
    InputField(Component).processEvent(AWTEvent) line: not available    
    InputField(Container).processEvent(AWTEvent) line: not available    
    InputField(Component).dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent) line: not available   
    InputField(Container).dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent) line: not available   
    InputField(Component).dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) line: not available   
    DefaultKeyboardFocusManager(KeyboardFocusManager).redispatchEvent(Component, AWTEvent) line: not available  
    DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Component, AWTEvent) line: not available    
    DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) line: not available 
    InputField(Component).dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent) line: not available   
    InputField(Container).dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent) line: not available   
    InputField(Component).dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) line: not available   
    SunToolkit$1.run() line: not available  
    PeerEvent(InvocationEvent).dispatch() line: not available   
    EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent, Object) line: not available  
    EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue, AWTEvent, Object) line: not available 
    EventQueue$3.run() line: not available  
    EventQueue$3.run() line: not available  
    AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]    
    ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(PrivilegedAction<T>, AccessControlContext, AccessControlContext) line: not available 
    EventQueue.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) line: not available  
    EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(int) line: not available 
    EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(int, Conditional, EventFilter) line: not available  
    EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(int, Conditional, Component) line: not available 
    EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(int, Conditional) line: not available    
    EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Conditional) line: not available 
    EventDispatchThread.run() line: not available
```

Note that InputField is a subclass of JTextField that with minor changes relating to rendering of the text.

All I can tell from the stack trace is that something on the EDT caused the InputField in MyPanel to gain focus.

Is there any further information I can get that will give me visibility on why the focus was gained by this component?

Comment: There shouldn't be any race condition since all Swing events should be performed on a single thread, the EDT. Consider trying to isolate the code that causes the problem by cutting away code until the problem goes away, and thereby trying to find the minimal code that reproduces the problem, and then post it here. Curious though: what are you using the FocusListener for?

Comment: I agree about the single thread but my concern is that swing may be performing the underlying rendering in a non deterministic order and that something inadvertently depends on that order. The focus listener is mostly just for debugging, it doesn't have any influence on when focus is gained, it just reacts to it.

Comment: `is that something on the EDT caused the InputField in MyPanel to gain focus.` please caused from ???, for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable, caused a.m. issue with focusGained from InputField redirected by JVM exception to MyPanel

Comment: Don't know if it will help but in the FocusEvent you can use the getOppositeComponent() method to tell where the focus came from.

Comment: @mKorbel, sorry I can't be more precise but I am unable to reproduce in an SSCCE so far.

Comment: @camickr, thanks, I can see the opposite component, it's another JTextField but that doesn't bring me closer to figuring out what caused the field in question to gain focus.

Comment: @PhilDin so have you solved your issue?

Comment: @SeniorJD, no I never got a resolution to the issue as described, we worked around it with business rules.

Comment: seems like i've found something...

Comment: If you need more information or if you need me to try something out, let me know.

Comment: It looks like a dirty hack, but you can try this: `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new MyAWTListener(), AWTEvent.FOCUS_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);` . Call it once per application session and notice that `MyAWTListener` should implement `AWTEventListener`. Just add the `System.out.println(e)` to your `eventDispatched(AWTEvent e)` implementation and explore the output. If that would help, let me know please ;)

Comment: may i ask what your *expected* behaviour is? this is not clear to me. maybe, when you give some more context, it is easier to imagine what the source of your problem could be. Maybe you build your gui dynamically, with different component layout each time? Maybe you change the FocusTraversalPolicy?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem,

at the end I just specified the focus hierarchy and took all control over focusing from java.
It goes a little something like this:

```
    // Setting The FOCUS Order.
    Vector<Component> order = new Vector<Component>(7);
    order.add(projectNameJTextField);
    order.add(companyJTextField);
    order.add(orderedByJTextField);
    order.add(phoneJTextField);
    order.add(jRadioNormalPriority);
    order.add(jRadioHighPriority);
    order.add(jCheckBox1);
    order.add(jCheckBox2);
    order.add(jCheckBox3);
    order.add(jCheckBox4);
    order.add(jCheckBox5);
    order.add(jCheckBox6);
    order.add(textDetailJTextArea);
    order.add(technitianJComboBox);
    order.add(aproxTimeJTextField);
    order.add(sendButton);

    // Sending the costume focus order to the focus Policy Class,
    MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy newPolicy = new MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy(order);
    setFocusTraversalPolicy(newPolicy);
```

**and you will also need this Class:**

```
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.FocusTraversalPolicy;
    import java.util.Vector;



    // This Class Helps to Set A Costume FOCUS Order.
    public class MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy extends FocusTraversalPolicy
    {
    Vector<Component> order;

    public MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy(Vector<Component> order) {
        this.order = new Vector<Component>(order.size());
        this.order.addAll(order);
    }
    public Component getComponentAfter(Container focusCycleRoot,
                                       Component aComponent)
    {
        int idx = (order.indexOf(aComponent) + 1) % order.size();
        return order.get(idx);
    }

    public Component getComponentBefore(Container focusCycleRoot,
                                        Component aComponent)
    {
        int idx = order.indexOf(aComponent) - 1;
        if (idx < 0) {
            idx = order.size() - 1;
        }
        return order.get(idx);
    }

    public Component getDefaultComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
        return order.get(0);
    }

    public Component getLastComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
        return order.lastElement();
    }

    public Component getFirstComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
        return order.get(0);
    }
    }
```

**(this is not my solution, and I cant remember where I got it from)**

Hope I could help :)

**Dave.**

Comment: _"I cant remember where I got it from"_ - Maybe straight from the [tutorial example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/FocusTraversalDemoProject/src/misc/FocusTraversalDemo.java) ;-)